# Android Maps GPS outlier

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

Using the Android maps api I'm creating polygons as I collect location data from every third point. The polygons track my position fairly well.

Problem is: Frequently the GPS returns points that are not remotely close especially when working around obstacles.

How can I filter my location data for outliers?

[image: You can kind of see that I don't want to include the outliers in my third points.]

Comment: just check the distance between the last point, if its greater than your maximum allowed diatance just ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes GPS has a hard time with especially around obstacles.  Powerlines, buildings, etc.  Simply filter them out.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (!location.hasAccuracy()) {
            return;
        }
        if (location.getAccuracy() > 10) {
            //possibly tell user gps accuracy with transparent circle like the maps 
            //application does.
            return;
        }

//process location accurate to 10 meters here
}
```